# Peer cli works but ExpressPeerServer doesnt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, peerjs, peer

I am trying to get an express peerJs server up and running locally over HTTPS. Now if i start the peerJS server via the CLI then i can connect to it just fine and everything works as it should, but once i try to run the peerJS server via my script, i cant connect to it. I get a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error in the console.

Working code:

**--server.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('https').Server(
  { key: fs.readFileSync('vuekey.pem'), cert: fs.readFileSync('vuecert.pem') },
  app
);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`);
});

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId);
    });
  });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

**--client.js**

```
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: '/',
  port: '3001',
});
```

I first run peerjs --port 3001 --sslkey 'E:\myPath\vuekey.pem' --sslcert 'E:\myPath\vuecert.pem' to manually start the PeerJS server. This all works fine and i have no issues. But i want to have the PeerJS server run as part of my main server script. So im doing that with `ExpressPeerServer`. So in my **server.js** file i add the below code, but thats when the console errors get thrown.

```
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  debug: true,
  port: '3001',
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('vuekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('vuecert.pem'),
  },
});

app.use('/peerjs', peerServer);
```

What is the PeerJS CLI doing differently than my server.js code? How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out finally. The express server and the peer server were in separate ports and i needed to add the path parameter in the Peer object.

**--server.js**

```
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  debug: true,
  port: '3000',
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('vuekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('vuecert.pem'),
  },
});
```

**--client.js**

```
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: '/', // This will force the localhost/IP of the machine
  path: '/peerjs', // Path that was specified in the server.js file for the peerServer's app.use() method.
  port: '3000', // This needs to be the same port as specified in the server.js
});
```

After making these minor changes, everything works as expected over HTTPS